# Condition only run ONCE (instead on all bars)

Tags: pine-script-v5

On checking for condition ***gap(high-low) > 0.1%***(which is met multiple times), the label only gets
rendered ONCE (instead of on relevant bars within  25 bar lookback).
Plz provide a solution.

***CODE :***
***Historical Bars***

```
//@version=5
indicator("PriceMomemtum",overlay = true,max_bars_back = 25)


gap = (math.abs(high - low)/low ) * 100 
//var gap = (math.abs(high - low)/low ) * 100 

if gap > 0.1
    var lbl = label.new(x = bar_index,y = na , text = na ,text_font_family = font.family_default ,xloc = xloc.bar_index,yloc =yloc.abovebar,style = label.style_arrowdown ,textcolor = color.white,size =size.small,textalign = text.align_left,tooltip = na)
    label.set_text(lbl,str.tostring(gap,"#.00")+"%")
    label.set_xy(lbl,bar_index,high )
```

***Realtime Bars***

```
//@version=5

indicator("PriceMomemtum",overlay = true,max_bars_back = 25)


if barstate.isrealtime
    gap = (math.abs(high - low)/low ) * 100 
    //var gap = (math.abs(high - low)/low ) * 100 
    if gap > 0.1
        var lbl = label.new(x = bar_index,y = na , text = na ,text_font_family = font.family_default ,xloc = xloc.bar_index,yloc =yloc.abovebar,style = label.style_arrowdown ,textcolor = color.white,size =size.small,textalign = text.align_left,tooltip = na)
        label.set_text(lbl,str.tostring(gap,"#.00")+"%")
        label.set_xy(lbl,bar_index,high )

        alert(str.tostring(time(syminfo.timezone)) + "(PriceMomentum)", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining "lbl" variable without "var"?

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKLZN.png)